# Google Bigquery SQL with clause `where 1=0` is not returning correct schema

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I recently added a new column in my BigQuery Table.
The following code snippet is used in legacy code to determine the table schema

```py
df = gbq.read_gbq('SELECT * FROM {}.{} where 1=0'.format(BIGQUERY_DATASET_NAME, table), project_id=project_id)
```

But the problem is that it is not returning the newly added column in the `df`. Although when I use some other condition like `1=3` in where clause or `limit 0` then it returns the correct schema.

Trying to understand what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing, it has to do with caching , you can always ask BQ not to use caching :

```
df =  gbq.read_gbq('SELECT * FROM {}.{} where 1=0'.format(...)
     , configuration = {'query': {'useQueryCache': False}} )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the column names - which I assume is the point of this - and can change the legacy code, perhaps a better approach would be to get it directly from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA view.

An example would be as follows:

```py
schema_query = f"""
SELECT column_name
  FROM {BIGQUERY_DATASET_NAME}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_name = '{table}'
"""

df = gbq.read_gbq(schema_query, project_id=project_id)
```

(if using python <3.6, revert to the `.format` syntax of course)

I have a hunch that this will avoid the problem you're encountering using the legacy code you're working with. I agree with the other answer that it's quite possible you're seeing cached results.